# Where must I upload my .unity3d

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

Ok the problem is when I try to put my "Unity Binary URL" to facebook's developers web page, it shows me an error message saying that my url must ends with .unity3d...

I try to upload it to... MEGA, Drive, OneDrive, DropBox and all of them give me a encripted url like this:

.../open?id=0B9ZOtq4g8KlZNXc5cndQcEY1RVE&authuser=0

(this project is already shared in public)

My Question is... where or how must I upload this file for get the correct url? 
I mean .../myfolder/myfile.unity3d ???

Answer (score 0):

for Google Drive youll get a link like this when you hit the share button and make sure its the share link to the WebPlayer folder

```
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B8mGQfidoAhjeFFiWC1r97s1SlE&usp=sharing
```

so the real key to this is after the id= part this

```
0B8mGQfidoAhjeFFiWC1r97s1SlE
```

you take that key and put it into facebook like this

```
https://googledrive.com/host/0B8mGQfidoAhjeFFiWC1r97s1SlE/WebPlayer.unity3d
```

Comment: Hi JRowan, I already do that, it doesnt work but, is true... Facebook take that url as a valid one but, when ur app trought the like that gives to u, I mean, facebook.com/yourappname , it show an error message when the web ends of loading our app

Comment: it works with mine, i dont completely understand what your trying to say

Comment: I dont know why it doesnt work for me, the link problem is solved but, now, when I try to play my game on facebook, it shows me an error message

Comment: When the unity interface load, the progress bar ends of loading, it says: "Failed to download data file" - "Error details" (as a link that popup an error message who say "Download failed, please retry" .... The link of my game is: https://apps.facebook.com/brickbreaker-beta/

Comment: you have to search around or ask another question, i just looked around for a while and i cant find anything, maybe facebook is down or try downloading unity web player lastest version, idk